# Evaluating a function over a lattice of unknown dimension using meshgrid and vectorize

Tags: python, numpy

When you know the number of dimensions of your lattice ahead of time, it is straight-forward to use meshgrid to evaluate a function over a mesh.

```
from pylab import *

lattice_points = linspace(0,3,4)
xs,ys = meshgrid(lattice_points,lattice_points)
zs = xs+ys # <- stand-in function, to be replaced by something more interesting
print(zs)
```

Produces

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 2.  3.  4.  5.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.  6.]]
```

But I would like to have a version of  something similar, for which the number of dimensions is determined during runtime, or is passed as a parameter.

```
from pylab import *

@np.vectorize
def fn(listOfVars) :
    return sum(listOfVars) # <- stand-in function, to be replaced 
                           # by something more interesting

n_vars = 2
lattice_points = linspace(0,3,4)
indices = meshgrid(*(n_vars*[lattice_points])) # this works fine

zs = fn(indices) # <-- this line is wrong, but I don't 
                 #     know what would work instead
print(zs)
```

Produces

```
[[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
  [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
  [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
  [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
  [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]]]
```

But I want it to produce the same result as above.

There is probably a solution where you can find the indices of each dimension and use `itertools.product` to generate all of the possible combinations of indices etc. etc., but is there not a nice pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Also have a look at `numpy.mgrid` (and note that you can build up the slices similar to `tuple(slice(start, stop) for (start, stop) in listOfVars)`).

Comment: In this 2D case (n_vars=2), the result should be exactly the same as that of the first bit of code given above, where the number of dimensions is known at the start. I will edit the above to make that clearer.

Comment: Where'd you get the idea `vectorize` was what you need? It calls the function separately for every element of the input array.

Comment: I misunderstood what you're asking. It seems like you're asking how to apply a function along a particular axis of an N-dimensional numpy array. Is that correct? (E.g. in your second case, you'd want `np.sum(indicies, axis=0)`). If so, have a look at `numpy.apply_along_axis`.

Comment: No -- I am afraid not :). I want to evaluate a function with N arguments at every point on an N-dimensional lattice, sampling the input space in a way that the first snipit of code I provided above does in 2D, but in N-dimensions, where N is not known until the program is run.

Comment: @weemattisnot - Actually, I think you are, though you may not realize it.  In your 2D case, meshgrid basically returns an 2xMxN 3d array (in `meshgrid`'s case, it's actually a list of 2D arrays, but that detail doesn't matter).  You're basically applying sum along the first axis to reduce the dimensionality of the input back down to 2D.

Answer (score 2):

Joe Kington and user2357112 have helped me to see the error in my ways. For those of you that would like to see a complete solution:

```
from pylab import *

## 2D "preknown case" (for testing / to compare output)
lattice_points = linspace(0,3,4)
xs,ys = meshgrid(lattice_points,lattice_points)
zs = xs+ys
print('2-D Case')
print(zs)

## 3D "preknown case" (for testing / to compare output)
lattice_points = linspace(0,3,4)
ws,xs,ys = meshgrid(lattice_points,lattice_points,lattice_points)
zs = ws+xs+ys
print('3-D Case')
print(zs)

## Solution, thanks to comments from Joe Kington and user2357112 
def fn(listOfVars) :
    return sum(listOfVars)

n_vars = 3 ## can change to 2 or 3 to compare to example cases above
lattice_points = linspace(0,3,4)
indices = meshgrid(*(n_vars*[lattice_points]))

zs = np.apply_along_axis(fn,0,indices)
print('adaptable n-D Case')
print(zs)
```